# A word that describes "doing something because you are told and not because you are informed"

Tags: single-word-requests

i.e. taking a medication that the doctor told you to, but you know nothing about it.

Comment: Can you use 'compliant' or 'submissive'?

Comment: so a word for "following orders" ?  perhaps "obeying"

Comment: *because I said so*

Answer (score 1):

Such an action could be described as "obligatory" or "compulsory," I think.  They have been told or required to do it, but don't necessarily want to, or know why.

Both of these words would describe an action that otherwise wouldn't be done if they didn't have to.  This doesn't clearly give the impression of being uninformed, though, just that the person has no other reason to do it other than that they know they have to.

Another option would be "blindly."  To do something blindly would mean that you don't know why you are doing it, or what the end result will be.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but I call it **"uninformed acceptance"**

> From the web:
>
> - "Bush encourages an **uninformed acceptance** of his assumption of the powers of commander-in-chief."
> - "...these are the unavoidable casualties of the widespread, **uninformed acceptance** of the importance of individual psychotherapy among the therapies available today."
> - "**Uninformed acceptance** of out-dated conventions cannot explain the vicious, spiteful rant against women's and girls' clubs."

Answer (score 0):

"Compliance"[1](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/compliance) or "deference"[2](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deference) would be my choices

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "obey".
A soldier 'obeys' an order or a citizen obeys the law, not because of their opinion of it.

> [***obey*** from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obey)
>   VERB
>
> 1 Submit to the authority of (someone) or comply with (a law)
>
> ‘I always obey my father’
>
> 1.1 Carry out (a command or instruction)
>
> ‘the officer was convicted for refusing to obey orders’
>
> ‘when the order was repeated, he refused to obey’
>
> 1.2 Behave in accordance with (a general principle, natural law, etc.)
>
> ‘the universe was complex but it obeyed certain rules’